# Java Functional Interfaces and Lambda Expressions

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

Given the following code, can someone please explain why the assertion returns true? Despite having searched around countlessly, I haven't been able to get any appropriate answer for why this might be the case, and what the Java feature(s) cause this behaviour and what restrictions / requirements I would have in similarly creating an interface such as this.

```
interface X {
  default int foo() {return 1;}
  String bar();
}

public class Exercise{
  public static void main(String[]arg){
    X foo1=()->"hello";
    assert (foo1.bar()).equals("hello");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you running it with assertions enabled? `-ea` key in command line.

Comment: @jpganz18 GitHub-style triple backticks are supported here now.

Comment: Yes I am sure that the code is being run with assertions enabled, and the assertion holds true. @talex

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A lambda expression is a concise way to create an instance of a *functional interface*, which is an interface with one abstract method.  Here, `X` is a functional interface, with abstract method `bar()`.  You could implement X with:

```
class XImpl implements X { 
    public String bar() { return "Foo"; }
}

X instance = new XImpl();
```

or an anonymous class

```
X anon = new X() { 
    public String bar() { return "foo"; }
};
```

or a lambda

```
X lambda = () -> "foo";
```

Each of these instantiates an implementation of `X`.  What may be confusing you is the concision of the lambda; because `X` has only one abstract method, `bar`, you don't have to say you are implementing `bar` -- the compiler figures it out.  Since `bar()` takes no arguments and returns `String`, the compiler ensures that the shape of the lambda is compatible with the shape of the sole abstract method.

Because an `X` has a `bar()` method,
you can call it on each of these instances:

```
String s1 = instance.bar();
assertEquals(s1, "hello");

String s2 = anon.bar();
assertEquals(s2, "hello");

String s3 = lambda.bar();
assertEquals(s3, "hello");
```

and you get the same result for each.

Answer (score 4):

Since method `foo()` has default implementation, you only need to specify `bar()` - which you do with `X foo1 = ()->"hello"`.

So, your `foo1.bar()` returns hello.

**UPD:** My answer may be unclear, so I should note that 'foo' is not treated as an abstract method by compiler (that lets your interface `X` satisfy the requirements of declaring functional interface). Brian explains it clearer and more detailed in his answer.